# ARM CM3 STM32F207 SRAM (RAM) space increase with SRAM2 ? BKPSRAM?

Tags: arm, ram, stm32f4discovery

### increase SRAM space on STM32F207

Hi,

I use the STM32F207ZFT but I haven't enough RAM space in SRAM1 for my application:

- Question1: if I don't use the SRAM2 region for the DMA's use (SRAM2 / 16KB: 0x2001 C000 - 0x2001 FFFF), could I use this memory area for normal RAM purpose (for extend the BSS area) in order to be contiguous with the SRAM1 (to increase the overall RAM size for uninitialized variables, initialized to 0)?
- Question2: could I use the backup SRAM (BKPSRAM / 4KB: 0x4002 4000 - 0x4002 4FFF) for storing some data buffers or some data arrays, as we could do it by using the BSS RAM area?
  Independently of its low consumption (on Vbat pin), is that the characteristics of this BKPSRAM are comparable to the SRAM1 area (access time ...)?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm very familiar with STM32F1xx and somewhat familiar with STM32F4xx, but never used STM32F2xx.

Regarding the first question: from reading the [manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00225773.pdf) (in particular, section 2.3.1), there's nothing special about SRAM2, except that an address in SRAM2 can be accessed at the same time as an address in SRAM1 is being accessed. Other than that, I can't spot any restrictions.

Regarding the second question: BKPSRAM is connected to the bus matrix through the AHB1 bus. In principle this bus runs at the same clock as the core, so if there is no bus contention the speed should be similar. If there are any wait states or anything that could delay accesses to BKPSRAM, I was unable to find it on the manual. Of course, if you have, say, a DMA transaction that is heavily accessing a peripheral connected to AHB1, then you would have bus contention which might delay accesses to BKPSRAM, whereas SRAM1 and SRAM2 have a direct connection, not shared by anything else, to the bus matrix. To summarize: you shouldn't have any problems.